# I am not sure how to input data into the map correctly

Tags: c++

The following is my code, I am reading data in from a file, and taking the data one line at a time and trying to insert it into a map.  I am not allowed to use more then one map.

```
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[]){

    char* file = argv[1];          // saves name of file
    ifstream infile ( file );      // Imported file
    map <string,  set < pair < string, string  > > > m;
    string data;
    string key;
    string year;
    string count;

    if(!infile){
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (!infile.eof() ){
        getline(infile, data);

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++ ){
            while ( data[i] != '\t'){
                key += data[i];
                i++;
            }
            i++;
            while ( data[i] != '\t'){
                year += data[i];
                i++;
            }
            i++;
            while ( data[i] != '\t'){
                count += data[i];
                i++;
            }
            cout << key << endl;
            cout << year << endl;
            cout << count << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }

        m.insert(key, set < pair < string, string > > ( year, count)  );
        key.clear();
        year.clear();
        count.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please ask a real question ? Compiler error would be fine too, if there aren't any, tell us what it is doing and what you expect. Explain us a little bit more what you are doing.

Comment: `while (!infile.eof() )` this is wrong. It will break for an empty file. It should be `while (getline(infile, data)) {}`

Comment: You should change your `while` loop to `while (getline(infile, data))`.  Read this article: [Why EOF in while loop is bad.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: You don't check for buffer overrun in your `while (data[i]` loops.

Comment: Try using `std::string::find_first_not_of("\t")` and `std::string::substr()`.

Answer (score 0):

You define here a map with a key and a value which is a set of pairs:

```
map <string,  set < pair < string, string  > > > m;
```

Is this really what you want ?

If you want to associate a pair of strings to a key, then define your map simply as:

```
map <string,  pair < string, string  >  > m;
```

To insert a new value you could then do:

```
m[key] = make_pair (year, count);
```

If on the other side, you'd prefer to associate several distinct pairs to a same key,  then you could use a **[`multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/)**

**P.S.:** It's not directly related to your question, but never llop on eof in C++.  Use  `while (getline(infile, data) )` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inserting in the map, but you want to insert in the set that is at the key **key** in the map

Try changing

```
 m.insert(key, set < pair < string, string > > ( year, count)  );
```

With:

```
m[key].insert(make_pair(year, count));
```

Or (more robust):

```
map <string,  set < pair < string, string  > > >::iterator it = m.find(key)
if (key == m.end) {
    set <pair<string,string>> s;
    s.insert(make_pair(year, count));
    m.insert(make_pair(key, s));
} else {
    it->second.insert(make_pair(year, count));
}
```